# command prompt simple form

Tags: forms, batch-file, cmd

I've got several batch files that set up template folder structures.  Here's an example below.

```
 %~d1
  CD "%~f1"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\1. All RAW"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\2. Chosen RAW"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\3. Editing Images"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\4. Production  Images"

  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\3. Editing Images\Archive"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\4. Production Images\In-Situ High Res JPG"
  MD "[ref] - 21-01-30 - [Description]\4. Production Images\In-Situ Low Res JPG"

  PAUSE
```

How could I add in a simple popup form that requests a reference and description as two simple text fields?  Then replaces the [ref] in the file name with the contents of the reference field, and the [Description] with the contents of the description field.  Can I also replace the date with today date in the format (yy-mm-dd) ?

Comment: Batch files are CLI, they do not interact with the GUI. You can have a prompt for input in the Command Prompt, using the `Set /P` command, but if you want a GUI form, you'll need to incorporate within your batch file, some call to a GUI capable program or scripting language.

Comment: Not bothered whether it's a GUI form or whether I just enter the input in the console - either approach works well for me

Answer (score 1):

VBS can be used to take input, with the input being stored in a file for reading back into the batch via Set /P:

```bat
@Echo off
:# Example input calls
 Call :Input "Enter REF string" Str.Ref "0" "Template Maker V0.01"
 Set Str.
 Call :Input "Enter Description string" 
 Set Rv
Goto :Eof
==============================================
:Input [Prompt] [Return Var] [Default] [Title]
:# Args optional - Default return Var if no Arg 2: Rv
 Del "%TEMP%\input.~in" 2> nul
 If "%~1" == "" (Set "PromptStr=Input Required.")Else Set "PromptStr=%~1"
 Set "Rv=Rv"
 If Not "%~2" == "" (
  Set "Rv=%~2"
  Set "%~2="
 )
 If "%~3" == "" (Set "Default=")Else Set "Default=%~3"
 If "%~4" == "" (Set "Title=")Else Set "Title=%~4"
:# Use a Vbs file to store input in text file
(
 Echo(Dim objFSO 'File System Object
 Echo(Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
 Echo(Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
 Echo(Const ForWriting = 2
 Echo(Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("%TEMP%\input.~in", ForWriting, True^)
 Echo(objTS.Write(InputBox("%PromptStr%","%Title%","%Default%"^)^)
 Echo(objTS.Close(^)
 Echo(Set bjFSO = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
 Echo(Set objTS = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
) >"%TEMP%\GetInput.vbs"

 START /wait "" "%TEMP%\GetInput.vbs"
:# Nul any prior input
 SET "Input="
:# Insist on user Input prior to attempting to load input.
 IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\input.~in" GOTO :Input
<"%TEMP%\input.~in" (
 SET /P "Input="
)
 If "%Input%"=="" (Echo Input Required&Goto :Input)Else Set "%Rv%=%Input%"
Exit /B 0
```

Comment: oh lord, you took his request for a popup form literally

Comment: Something From a game I started but never finished.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
 %~d1
  CD "%~f1"

For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
echo %mydate%
set /p var_ref="Enter reference "
set /p var_des="Enter description "

  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\1. All RAW"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\2. Chosen RAW"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\3. Editing Images"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\4. Production Images"

  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\3. Editing Images\Archive"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\4. Production Images\In-Situ High Res JPG"
  MD "%var_ref% - %mydate% - %var_des%\4. Production Images\In-Situ Low Res JPG"

  PAUSE
```

T3RR0R answer works well but this approach is a lot simpler - thanks to Compo for pointing me in the right direction.